# Search parameters are lost when table column is sorted in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, pagination

I am doing searching and sorting with pagination in PHP. These are working OK. But after searching if I do sorting on table header columns then search parameters are lost and table returns back to its default view. Here is my PHP code -

```
<?php
include("includes/db-config.php");
include("includes/pagination.php");

// table name
$table = "tb_categories";

// order by column names array
$orderby_arr = array("category_id" => "Category ID", "category_name" => "Category Name");

// sorting order ASC or DESC array
$sort_arr = array("asc", "desc");

// set default values
$orderby = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? $_GET['orderby'] : "category_name";
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "asc";

// get opposite $sort_order value for producing toggle links in the table heading
if($sort == "asc")
{
    $sort_order = "desc";
}
else
{
    $sort_order = "asc";
}

// if search request comes
if(isset($_GET['btnsearch']))
{
    $search = isset($_GET['txtsearch']) ? $_GET['txtsearch'] : '';
    if($search != '')
    {
        // form a simple LIKE '%search_term%' comparison
        $where_clause = sprintf("WHERE `category_name` LIKE '%%%s%%'", mysql_real_escape_string($search));
    }
    else
    {
        $where_clause = '';
    }
}
// default
else
{
    $search = '';
    $where_clause = '';
}

// get total number of records
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table $where_clause";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
list($total_records) = mysql_fetch_row($rs);

// number of records per page
$records_per_page = 3;

// total number of pages
$total_pages = ceil($total_records/$records_per_page);


if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
{
    if($_GET['page'] >= $total_pages)
    {
        $page = $total_pages;
    }
    else if($_GET['page'] <= 0)
    {
        $page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
    }
}
else
{
    // default page on loading
    $page = 1;
}

// first row starts at 0
$start_row = ($page - 1) * $records_per_page;
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table $where_clause ORDER BY $orderby $sort LIMIT $start_row, $records_per_page";
$rs = mysql_query($query);

?>

<form method="get" action="">
Type Keyword: <input type="text" name="txtsearch" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="Search" />
</form>


<table width="50%" align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Sr. No.</th>
        <?php
        // dynamically produce table columns
        foreach($orderby_arr as $key => $value)
        {
            echo "<th><a href='?orderby=" . $key . "&sort=" . $sort_order . "'>" . $value . "</a></th>";
        }
        ?>
        <th>Category Description</th>
    </tr>

        <?php
        // fetch rows
        $srno = 1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $srno; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['category_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['category_desc']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $srno++;
        }
        ?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
        <div id="pagination">
        <?php echo getPagination($page, $total_pages); ?>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On searching for a keyword "cricket" I have the following URL -

```
/?txtsearch=cricket&btnsearch=Search
```

But the table column header (category id or category name) is showing just following -

```
/?orderby=category_id&sort=desc
```

So how can i retain or preserve search parameters so that it append to column header. But on default view since there will no search parameter then the column header will only have above second URL. And since I also have pagination therefore the search parameters along with table column header sorting parameters should be attached with page id. I think once the search parameters start working with sorting then there should not be any problem with pagination since I am using the following code in pagination function -

```
// only modify the 'page number' value, all others left as is
$_GET['page'] = $i;
$q = http_build_query($_GET, '', '&amp;');
$pagination .= " <a href='?$q'>$i</a> ";
```

The value of $i is coming from for loop and pagination is working correctly; no problem with it.

How can we can do this? Thanks to all my frz in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rebuild query string like this -

```
$txtsearch = $search;
$btnsearch = $_GET['btnsearch'];
$orderby = 'category_name';
$order = $sort_order;


    $query_string = array(
                        "txtsearch" => $txtsearch,
                        "btnsearch" => $btnsearch,
                        "orderby" => $orderby,
                        "order" => $order,
                    );


$sort_link = "?" . http_build_query($query_string, "", "&");
```